# Bootstrap image even, odd position

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am developing a CMS for a costumer and have to print data lint a list (code included at the bottom) in an even and odd position. I tried to apply a lot of ways but doesn't works properly.

Should i include all the parent classes?

Here is the corresponding code:

```
 @extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    @foreach($exhibs as $exhib)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ]">
                <ul class="event-list">
                    <li>
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="nth-child(even) img { float: right; }" alt="Independence Day" src="{{ asset('/images/events/' . $exhib->img) }}" />
                        <div class="info">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                @if(App::getLocale() == "hu")
                                    <a href="{{  URL::to('exhib/show/' . $exhib->id . '/hu') }}">{{ $exhib->title_hu }}</a>
                                @elseif(App::getLocale() == "en")
                                    {{ $exhib->title_en }}
                                @elseif(App::getLocale() == "tr")
                                    {{ $exhib->title_tr }}
                                @endif
                            </h2>
                            <p class="desc">
                                @if(App::getLocale() == "hu")
                                    {{ $exhib->desc_hu }}
                                @elseif(App::getLocale() == "en")
                                    {{ $exhib->desc_en }}
                                @elseif(App::getLocale() == "tr")
                                    {{ $exhib->desc_tr }}
                                @endif
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use nth-child selectors inline.

Put this in the head of your page instead:

```
<style>
.event-list li:nth-child(even) img { float: right; }
</style>
```

And remove the inline style from the images.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! It works but now evry item moved to the right, it's because of the loop or did i missed something else?